# Prolog rule keeps returning false

Tags: prolog

I am really new to Prolog and I am working on this project. I have data on the british monarchy and I am working on a "heir" rule that finds the heir to the throne or tells me if my input is the valid heir to the throne.

I have this data regarding the british monarchy:

```
male(georgeIII).
male(georgeIV).
male(frederick).
male(williamIV).
male(edward).
male(ernest_augustus).
male(augustus).
male(adolphus).
male(george1).
male(francis).
male(albert).
male(edwardVII).
male(alfred).
male(leopold).
male(albert_victor).
male(georgeV).
male(edwardVIII).
male(georgeVI).
male(henry).
male(george2).
male(john).


female(charlotte).
female(mary).
female(caroline).
female(charlotte1).
female(victoria).
female(victoriaI).
female(augusta).
female(mary_adelaide).
female(mary1).
female(victora1).
female(alexandra).
female(alice).
female(helena).
female(beatrice).
female(louise_victoria).
female(maud).
female(mary2).


born(georgeIII, 1738).
born(georgeIV, 1762).
born(frederick, 1763).
born(williamIV, 1765).
born(edward, 1767).
born(ernest_augustus, 1771).
born(augustus, 1773).
born(adolphus, 1774).
born(george1, 1819).
born(albert, 1819).
born(francis, 1837).
born(edwardVII, 1841).
born(alfred, 1844).
born(leopold, 1853).
born(albert_victor, 1864).
born(georgeV, 1865).
born(edwardVIII, 1894).
born(georgeVI, 1895).
born(henry, 1900).
born(george2, 1902).
born(john, 1905).


born(charlotte, 1744).
born(caroline, 1768).
born(mary, 1776).
born(victoria, 1786).
born(charlotte1, 1796).
born(augusta, 1797).
born(victoriaI, 1819).
born(victora1, 1819).
born(mary_adelaide, 1833).
born(alice, 1843).
born(alexandra, 1844).
born(helena, 1844).
born(beatrice, 1857).
born(mary1, 1867).
born(louise_victoria, 1867).
born(maud, 1869).
born(mary2, 1897).


parents(edwardVII, alexandra, albert_victor).
parents(edwardVII, alexandra, georgeV).
parents(edwardVII, alexandra, louise_victoria).
parents(edwardVII, alexandra, maud).
parents(albert, victoriaI, victoria1).
parents(albert, victoriaI, edwardVII).
parents(albert, victoriaI, alice).
parents(albert, victoriaI, alfred).
parents(albert, victoriaI, helena).
parents(albert, victoriaI, arthur).
parents(albert, victoriaI, leopold).
parents(albert, victoriaI, beatrice).
parents(francis, mary_adelaide, mary1).
parents(edward, victoria, victoriaI).
parents(georgeIV, caroline, charlotte1).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, georgeIV).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, frederick).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, williamIV).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, edward).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, ernest_augustus).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, augustus).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, adolphus).
parents(georgeIII, charlotte, mary).
parents(adolphus, augusta, george1).
parents(adolphus, augusta, mary_adelaide).
parents(georgeV, mary1, edwardVIII).
parents(georgeV, mary1, georgeVI).
parents(georgeV, mary1, mary2).
parents(georgeV, mary1, henry).
parents(georgeV, mary1, george2).
parents(georgeV, mary1, john).


year(1780).
```

I am working on a Prolog rule called "heir" that is defined as follows: `heir(<valid heir>, <heirs parent>, <sequence law type>, <gender law type>)`

The gender and sequence rules regarding the monarchy are as follows:

```
%gender law:
%  strict_agnatic:
%    primary - only males of the parents dynasty may inherit
%    secondary - if no valid primary heirs, only males of parents children may inherit
%  strict_enatic
%    primary - only females of the parents dynasty may inherit
%    secondary - if no valid primary heirs, only females of parents children may inherit
%  agnatic_cognatic
%    primary - males of the parents dynasty may inherit
%    secondary - if no valid primary heirs, females of parents dynasty may inherit
%              - female heirs with male children are preferred
%  enatic_cognatic
%    primary - females of the parents dynasty may inherit
%    secondary - if no valid primary heirs, males of parents dynasty may inherit
%              - male heirs with female children are preferred

%sequence law:
%  primogeniture: oldest eligible successor is heir
%  ultimogenture: youngest eligible successor is heir
```

This is the current code I have for the heir rule:

```
age(NAME, Z):- born(NAME, X), year(Y), Z is Y-X.
child_of(X, Y):- parents(Y,_,X);parents(_,Y,X).
is_older(A, B):- age(A, AG), age(B, AG0), \+(A = B), AG > AG0.
is_younger(A, B):- age(A, AG), age(B, AG0), \+(A = B), AG < AG0.


elder_child(PAR, CHD0, CHD1):- child_of(CHD0, PAR),child_of(CHD1, PAR),
                CHD0 \= CHD1,is_older(CHD0, CHD1).

eldest_child(PAR, CHD):- child_of(CHD, PAR),\+elder_child(PAR, _, CHD).


younger_child(PAR, CHD0, CHD1):- child_of(CHD0, PAR),child_of(CHD1, PAR),
                CHD0 \= CHD1,is_younger(CHD0, CHD1).


youngest_child(PAR, CHD):- child_of(CHD, PAR),\+younger_child(PAR, _, CHD).

% this is the code I am working on:
heir(HEIR, PARENT, strict_agnatic, primogeniture) :-
    male(HEIR),
    child_of(HEIR, PARENT),
    eldest_child(PARENT, HEIR).

heir(HEIR, PARENT, strict_agnatic, ultimogeniture) :-
    male(HEIR),
    child_of(HEIR, PARENT),
    youngest_child(PARENT, HEIR).

heir(HEIR, PARENT, strict_enatic, primogeniture) :-
    female(HEIR),
    child_of(HEIR, PARENT),
    eldest_child(PARENT, HEIR).

heir(HEIR, PARENT, strict_enatic, ultimogeniture) :-
    female(HEIR),
    child_of(HEIR, PARENT),
    youngest_child(PARENT, HEIR).

heir(HEIR, PARENT, agnatic_cognatic, primogeniture) :-
    male(HEIR),
    child_of(HEIR, PARENT),
    eldest_child(PARENT, HEIR).
heir(HEIR, PARENT, agnatic_cognatic, primogeniture) :-
    female(HEIR),
    child_of(HEIR, PARENT),
    \+ heir(_, PARENT, agnatic_cognatic, primogeniture),
    eldest_child(PARENT, CHILD), male(CHILD).
```

Now, when I try to test this with the input `heir(X, georgeIII, ultimogeniture, strict_enatic).` I get `false` instead of getting `X = mary`. I do not how to fix this.

I tried multiple test cases and they all fail:
the first line is the input and the following line is the expected result. I keep getting "false" and it never tells me what `X` should be.

```
%testcases:
%    heir(georgeIV, georgeIII, primogeniture, agnatic_cognatic).
%    true ?
%
%    heir(georgeIV, georgeIII, ultimogeniture, agnatic_cognatic).
%    no
%
%    heir(X, georgeIII, primogeniture, strict_enatic).
%    X = mary
%        yes
%
%    heir(X, georgeIII, ultimogeniture, strict_enatic).
%    X = mary
%        yes
%
%   (if you comment out mary from female, born and parents):
%    heir(X, georgeIII, ultimogeniture, strict_enatic).
%    X = charlotte1 ? ;
%    X = victoriaI ? ;
%    X = mary_adelaide ? ;
%    no
%
%   heir(X, georgeIII, ultimogeniture, enatic_cognatic).
%   X = adolphus ? ;
%   no
%
%   heir(X, georgeIII, primogeniture, enatic_cognatic).
%   X = georgeIV ? ;
%   no
```

Comment: This is a huge question. Could you make a smaller example?

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Use variable names, and predicate names, which are clear rather than confusing. E.g. child_father_mother(Child, Father, Mother) instead of parents(X, Y, Z)

Comment: Compare code `heir(HEIR, PARENT, strict_enatic, ultimogeniture)` and query `heir(X, georgeIII, ultimogeniture, strict_enatic)` you appear to have strict_enatic and ultimogeniture switched around in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, seems that you misplaced  `<sequence law type>` and  `<gender law type>` in a lot of your test, so I tested all of your test by inverting them:

1. `heir(georgeIV, georgeIII, agnatic_cognatic,primogeniture).` work for me
2. You didn't defined/gave us `agnatic_cognatic` for `ultimogeniture`
3. For  `heir(X, georgeIII, strict_enatic, primogeniture).`, this is more of a design problem, because  you seem to search for the youngest/oldest and then check if it's a male/female, and (unless I misunderstood laws), heir can be not the Oldest/youngest of the sibling.
4. `heir(X, georgeIII, strict_enatic, ultimogeniture).` works for me.
5. Same as 2.
   (for test 5,6,7, you should try something like `heir(X, georgeIII, Y , Z ).`, to try visualising what you missed.

Hope I helped you